# Flutter - get the dates of all the days of the week

Tags: flutter, filter, sqflite

I have a flutter database that stores the date of inputted data.
I used this database to filter it into the seven days of the week. at first i tried using for example

```
DateTime.sunday
```

which imputed 7, not what i am after.

I am not sure if there is a library for it as i did search, I want to get the dates of, for instance, all Sundays. Todays date is 17/12/23, i would then want 10/12/23 and 24/12/23 and so on so that my rawQuery in DB has a date to refer and filter through.

i did look into an example that does this however im looking for something more robust say.

this is the example

```
List<DateTime> findPreviousSaturdays({
  required int count,
  DateTime? from,
}) {
  // End recursion
  if (count == 0) {
    return [];
  }

  // Defaults to now
  final _from = from ?? DateTime.now();

  return [findPreviousSaturday(from: _from)] +
      findPreviousSaturdays(
        count: count - 1,
        from: _from.subtract(Duration(days: 7)),
      );
}
```

if someone could refer to me a library of some sort it would be golden.

cheers

Comment: Note that `Duration(days: 7)` is 7 * 24 hours, so [you might get results you don't expect if spanning Daylight Saving Time events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68214911/) if you are in a locale that observes DST.  If you care only about the date component, then it'd be better to operate on UTC `DateTime` objects (or to use something like [`addCalendarDays`](https://pub.dev/documentation/basics/latest/date_time_basics/DateTimeBasics/addCalendarDays.html)).

Comment: Also, if you have a collection of existing `DateTime` objects and just want to filter it (instead of generating new `DateTime` objects), just iterate over them and check the [`weekday`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/weekday.html) property of each one.

Comment: i will definitely try the weekday property, i am anticipating it to work. My goal is to check what day the saved DateTime data is, which i think i can get through this, cheers, ill let you know if that works

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for another way to write the function, here's one:

```dart
Iterable<DateTime> findPreviousSaturdays({
  required int count,
  DateTime? from,
}) sync* {
  var date = from ?? DateTime.now();

  while (count-- > 0) {
    date = date.subtractDays(7);
    yield date;
  }
}
```

Comment: and im guessing i could also achieve future saturdays

Comment: Yes, you can do it by using `addDays` instead.